# Duplicate logging lo4j2.xml (JBoss EAP 7)

Tags: xml, logging, log4j2

I have the following log4j2.xml file for configuring logging. The issue is there are duplicate logs sent to the server.log and to the specified directory below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <!-- Configure your console appender if needed -->
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS} [%-5level] (%t) [%logger{36} - %M]: %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                     fileName="/logs/demo-service/demo-service-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log"
                     filePattern="/logs/demo-service/demo-service-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS} [%-5level] (%t) [%logger{36} - %M]: %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="25 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="/logs/demo-service/" maxDepth="2">
                    <IfFileName glob="demo-service-*.log.gz"/>
                    <IfLastModified age="1d"/>
                </Delete>
                <ZipCompressAction/>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: You configured Log4j to log to both `System.out` and a file. Hence the double logging.